# Como evitar que alertdialog.builder se cierre si no se selecciona una opcion?

Tags: android-studio, alertdialog

quiero evitar que el AlertDialog.Builder se cierre si no se seleccion una opcion, ya probe quitando los `dialog.dismiss()` pero igual cuando doy en el boton aceptar sin haber seleccionado una opcion se cierra, quiero que el AlertDialog se mantenga ahi visible y cuando se presione en el boton Aceptar sin haber seleccionado una opcion que este muestre un Toast diciendo que debe seleccionar una opcion.

```
imageButtonAddNewClient.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String itemOptions[] = {"Cliente activo", "Cliente inactivo"};
            new AlertDialog.Builder(NewClient.this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom)
                    .setTitle("Agregar nuevo cliente:")
                    .setSingleChoiceItems(itemOptions, posicionSeleccionadaStateClient, null)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setNeutralButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
                    .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            intent = new Intent(NewClient.this, ActivityNewClient.class);
                            posicionSeleccionadaStateClient = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getListView().getCheckedItemPosition();
                            if(posicionSeleccionadaStateClient == 0){
                                intent.putExtra("code", 0);
                            }else if(posicionSeleccionadaStateClient == 1){
                                intent.putExtra("code", 1);

                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(NewClient.this, "Seleccione una opción.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            startActivity(intent);
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Deseas evitar se cierre al dar clic en el "back button".

Comment: "Me sale error en la linea: AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewClient.this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom). Me pide que cambie el AlertDialog por AlertDialog.Builder y si lo cambio me sale error en el metodo dialog.setShowListener()."
**Como lo solucionaste Leonidas?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

para lograr eso lo que hay que hacer es sobreescribir el onClick del boton aceptar, ahi dentro validar que los datos esten como vos queres y segun eso hacer o no el dismiss.

Primero hay que setear en null el onclick del positive button porque lo vamos a sobre escribir.

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewClient.this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom)
   .setTitle("Agregar nuevo cliente:")
   .setSingleChoiceItems(itemOptions, posicionSeleccionadaStateClient, null)
   .setCancelable(false)
   .setNeutralButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
   .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", null);
```

Ahora agregamos un OnShowListener para poder sobreescribir el onclick despues de que se crea al dialog.

```
dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

   @Override
   public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {

      Button button = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
      button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {

            if (todo ok?){ //Aca valida lo que necesites
               dialog.dismiss();
            }
         }
      });
   }
});
dialog.show();
```

Comment: Me sale error en la linea: AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewClient.this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom). Me pide que cambie el AlertDialog por AlertDialog.Builder y si lo cambio me sale error en el metodo dialog.setShowListener().

Comment: Problema resuelto, gracias.