# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que AlertDialog se cierre solo cuando ya he elegido una de las opciones?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo un AlertDialog el cual me muestra algunas opciones, el problemas es que el usuario puede cerrar el AlertDialog sin haber escogido ninguna opción. yo lo que quiero es obligar al usuario a que seleccione una opción antes de cerrar. Ya intente poner una condición en el setPositiveButton en el que verifico que si es null una variable no haga nada... pero resulta que sin importar lo que ponga en el setPositiveButton este cierra el dialogo.

```java
public AlertDialog createRadioListDialog(final CharSequence[] items, final String title, final int post) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(title)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setSingleChoiceItems(items, posi, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    // codigo el cual guarda la opcion que selecciono.

                }
            }).setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_ok),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if(!variable == null){
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}
```

Comment: Esta repuesta explica como hacerlo. Básicamente solo tienes que obtener el `positiveButton` del `alertDialog` y anular el evento `onClick`. Para más información visita el enlace. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620444/how-to-prevent-a-dialog-from-closing-when-a-button-is-clicked/7636468#7636468

Comment: Hola Jhon creo que esta respuesta es justo lo que estas buscando:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/226590/como-evitar-que-alertdialog-builder-se-cierre-si-no-se-selecciona-una-opcion/226608#226608

Comment: @ErickSilva en estos casos puedes votar a cerrar como duplicado, tu respuesta en realidad es lo que pregunta el OP en esta publicación ,  saludos!

Comment: @ErickSilva si lo intente y me funciono... pero tengo un inconveniente, y es que la primera ves que sale el dialogo me pide dar click 2 veces...

Comment: Ya lo soluciones.... estaba haciendo 2 veces el .show().Gracias